# SSIS Filename variable with wildcards

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking at creating a SSIS package that copies the latest file from a specific directory. There are multiple files output to the directory each day and each gets date and time stamped in the file name

FLATFILE_20150909_130801.txt

FLATFILE_20150909_230508.txt

I am only interested in the latest file during the day. Which will always have the same prefix 23 . I’ve written the expression as

```
"\\\\DESTINATION\\FLATFILE"+ "_"+ (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate() ) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) + "_"+ "23"+ "****"+ ".sqb"
```

Which returns  FLATFILE_20150909_23****.txt

Is there any way to assign wildcards to the characters in the string **** so it ignores these??

Comment: I think you can use standard Windows file wildcards in the [Foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187670.aspx) file loop component, so you could "loop" through one file by specifying "FLATFILE_20150909_23*.txt"...

Comment: Or loop through all of them, and use a script component to check if it's the "23" file.